# Dash plotly / CSS. customize marker style - Gradient color for bar chart

Tags: css, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I would appreciate it if someone can help me.

I would like to have a gradient for my bar chart instead of one color.
something like this:

[image]

```
go.Bar( x=df2.date,y=df2.ans,yaxis='y1', textposition='auto', marker={'color':'##7FFF00' )
```

I have also tried to do it with

```
marker={'color':list(range(-10,10))
```

but it gives me a general gradient from right to left.

I have also tried to add css to asset:

```
.grad{ color: linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow)}
```

but I couldn't manage to use it.

Looking forward to your help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can add 'colorscale': 'YlOrRd' to your marker dict!

```
go.Bar( x=df2.date,y=df2.ans,yaxis='y1', textposition='auto', marker={'color':'##7FFF00', 'colorscale': 'YlOrRd'})
```

`colorscale` also have these options (as strings like above): Greys,YlGnBu,Greens,YlOrRd,Bluered,RdBu,Reds,Blues,Picnic,Rainbow,Portland,Jet,Hot,Blackbody,Earth,Electric,Viridis,Cividis.

Check out this link for more info https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/

Comment: thank you for your reply, actually the figure works fine, I just wanted to change the color of bars in the chart. in the marker. I mean instead of one color in `marker={'color':'##7FFF00'}` I wanted to have gradient color ( 2 colors same as the image) @ebeach

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I edited my answer, which should solve your problem now :)